# NameError: name 'BaseCommand' is not defined

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create custom management command and I am getting following error when I run my command .

command :- `python manage.py test_command`

error :- `NameError: name 'BaseCommand' is not defined`

My command is at correct place as per [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) and I can share code snippet of command if necessary .

test_command.py

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        ...some code...
        self.stdout.write('Successfully executed')
```

Comment: You may not have imported `BaseCommand` show us code for your command.

Comment: Without some code from manage.py,it is difficult to answer. It seems that you are not declaring/importing `BaseCommand`

Comment: Nope. Let me share the code .

Comment: Not sure if we have to import anything in manage.py. I highly doubt it.

Comment: when you get the error, in which file and line is it?

Comment: test_command.py. line with code - class Command(BaseCommand):

Comment: I've tried this code on my Ubuntu - python2.7 and it works ok, so I assume the error should be somewhere else

Comment: I am also using python 2.7.2 . dnt know why its not working